# Why is JBOSS preventing web browsing?

Tags: java, jboss

I have an odd situation: basically, when I run JBOSS on Windows 7 pro (after directly downloading it from the JBOSS site), I am no longer able to browse the web. Specifically, only IE works but other browsers (FF, Chrome) do not.

Post 80 is not blocked by an process. What steps can I do to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: any proxy setting on your FF and Chrome ?

Comment: yes, fixing the proxy settings (turning proxies off) in FF and Chrome works (feel free to answer the question)

Comment: Which JBOSS software do you mean? My search results showed me a whole lot of software, provided by the JBoss company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss consumes about 6-10 ports and port 80 isn't used unless you specifically configured it to do so.   You can probably identify the ports that Jboss is using by running this command at a dos prompt:  "netstat -anb"  .

When running JBoss, it is impossible that it would prevent your browser to work unless your browser was configured for a local proxy on one of the ports that JBoss is using.